# sign rpm package error Header V4 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID BAD

Tags: digital-signature, rpm, gnupg

I want to sign RPM Packages with my GNU-GPG Key. I have done the following steps:

Generate key:

gpg --no-default-keyring --full-gen-key

create ~/.rpmmacros

```
%_topdir %(echo $HOME)/rpmbuild

%__arch_install_post \
    [ "%{buildarch}" = "noarch" ] || QA_CHECK_RPATHS=1 ; \
    case "${QA_CHECK_RPATHS:-}" in [1yY]*) /usr/lib/rpm/check-rpaths ;; esac \
    /usr/lib/rpm/check-buildroot
%_signature gpg
%_gpg_path /root/.gnupg
%_gpg_name testuser
%_gpgbin /usr/bin/gpg2
%__gpg_sign_cmd %{__gpg} gpg --force-v3-sigs --batch --verbose --no-armor --passphrase-fd 0 --no-secmem-warning -u "%{_gpg_name}" -sbo %{__signature_filename} --digest-algo sha256 %{__plaintext_filename}'
```

export public key

```
gpg --export -a testuser > ~/public.asc
```

import key to rpm

```
rpm --import /root/public.asc
```

sign a package

```
rpm --addsign packetbeat-8.5.3-x86_64.rpm
packetbeat-8.5.3-x86_64.rpm:
gpg: WARNING: unsafe permissions on homedir '/root/.gnupg'
gpg: writing to 'packetbeat-8.5.3-x86_64.rpm.sig'
gpg: pinentry launched (1861 curses 1.2.1 /dev/pts/0 xterm - 20620/1000/5 0/0 0)
gpg: RSA/SHA256 signature from: "3AEA484FD5C227E4 Testuser (mycomment) <testuser@testuser.de>"
```

verify the package

```
[root@fedora opt]# rpm -Kv packetbeat-8.5.3-x86_64.rpm
packetbeat-8.5.3-x86_64.rpm:
    Header V4 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID d5c227e4: BAD
    Header SHA256 digest: OK
    Header SHA1 digest: OK
    Payload SHA256 digest: OK
    MD5 digest: OK
```

check the imported key

The signature is not valid. Why? My RPM Version is 4.18.0